# Struggling with floatrow (side by side image / caption)

Tags: floatrow, sidecap

Two questions:

The 50% figure at the top is slightly too wide. What would be the correct way to tell the caption to be a smaller?

The 2/3 figure should be 2/3 image and 1/3 (a bit less) caption. The size of the caption is about right in my example, but I don't know how to stretch the image. How can I stretch the image?

This is my TeX input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt

Image plus caption should be full width, but no more.

\begin{figure}
  \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=.5\linewidth}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
  {\caption{50 percent - looks almost good. A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.}\label{animage}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
  \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=.3\linewidth}}]{figure}
  {\caption{33 percent caption? The image should be about 66\% A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.}\label{animage}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `floatwidth=sidefil` not `[\FBwidth]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt

Image plus caption should be full width, but no more.

\begin{figure}[!h] %only to get both on one page
  \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{floatwidth=sidefil,capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=.5\linewidth}}]{figure}
  {\caption{50 percent - looks almost good. A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.}\label{animage}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[!h]
  \floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{floatwidth=sidefil,capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=.3\linewidth}}]{figure}
  {\caption{33 percent caption? The image should be about 66\% A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.}\label{animage}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-4x3.pdf}}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I was not too far off :-) Thank you very much.